# Can ViewComponent have child-components?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I would like to have something like:

```
<vc:grid title="hello world">
    <vc:image-card img="/img/myimage.png" title="test"/>
    <vc:project-card title="test"/>
</vc:grid
```

Is this possible with .net core ViewComponents?